# Cannot resolve method startActivityforResults in this code

Tags: java, android

Why cannot resolve this method in a class? This class is out off main android class. If I put the method in main class work fine, but not in other class.

```
class blu {

        public blu(){

        }

        public boolean comprobarBluetooth(Context context){


            CharSequence text = "No tiene Bluetooth";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            //mirem si hi ha bluetooth al aparell
            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if(mBluetoothAdapter==null) {

                //disparo un toast per informar

                return false;
            }else{

                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    //si està apagat obrim el dialeg per activarlo.
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                   startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }//SI startActivityForResult torna un OK faig return true, i executo el metode de buscar dispositivos

            }
           return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` is [a method on `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). You cannot call `startActivityForResult()` from some random Java class. You need to call `startActivityForResult()` on an `Activity`, specifically the activity where you plan on getting the results via `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 6):

If `context` is an instance of Activity you can use:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

If it is not an instance of Activity you will get an exception.

Answer (score -2):

`startActivityForResult` is a method of the `Context` class. You will have to call `context.startActivityForResult(...)`.